# The "For You" page in my team seems to be stuck on 1 notification, even though it says I'm all caught up

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams, notifications

Ever since I've been de-activated and re-activated, my team shows 1 notification and I *cannot* dismiss it.

[image: "For You" page showing 1 notification]

This shows on all of my SE sites:

[image: Stack Overflow home page with the team showing 1 notification]

Answer (score -5, accepted):

After receiving a notification, it's now fixed.  I suppose it's a permanent, relatively easy workaround but still a workaround (and it would require getting a notification, which on some teams would require creating a spam post).

Answer (score -5):

For now, I've added

```
meta.stackoverflow.com###left-sidebar > div.left-sidebar--sticky-container.js-sticky-leftnav:first-child > nav > ol.nav-links > li:last-child > ol.nav-links > li.js-team-nav-link:last-child > a.pl8.js-gps-track.nav-links--link > div.grid.ai-center > div.grid--cell.px4.ml-auto:last-child > span.s-badge.s-badge__sm.bg-blue-600.fc-white.bc-transparent
```

to the list of custom ads to block.  A very patchwork solution, but it works.